# What do you call people who are good at keeping others' secrets?

Tags: vocabulary, adjectives

What do you call a person who is good at keeping others' secrets and won't reveal or disclose them to other people, so you can trust them in telling your secrets (to them)?

I have found "[secretive](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/secretive)", but according to its meaning people who are secretive are good at keeping secrets about themselves; so I don't think it can be the answer to my question.

Comment: "a confidant" might be what you are looking for - a close friend or associate to whom secrets are confided or with whom private matters and problems are discussed.

Comment: Yes, @Morgan FR, I exactly mean such people you described. :)

Comment: @MorganFR, can I use "trustworthy" too? ( Would it mean they are good at keeping secrets?)

Comment: trustworthy is broader, you could lend them some money and you can trust them to give it back for instance, but a confidant is definetly a trustworthy person.

Comment: That person is called a **decedent**.

Comment: @TRomano, do you mean that only "dead people" can keep our secrets? ( decedent= A dead person)? or "decedent" has another meaning?

Comment: I think TRomano is making a joke, yes.  There's an old joke that two people can keep a secret, if one of them is dead.

Comment: Interesting, @stengdon. We have that joke in Persian too. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say they are a "Good confidante"

as per MorganFR confidant**e** is gender specific for Women, there is also confidant

Comment: Confidant***e*** only applies to women.

Comment: TIL.. Confidant vs Confidante

Answer (score 2):

If you want an adjective, then [discreet](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discreet) fits the bill: careful not to cause embarrassment or attract too much attention, especially by keeping something secret